# Firebase Dynamic Link Page Not Opening In App (iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am implementing passwordless sign in with Firebase using dynamic links. When a user clicks on the sign in link in their email, the default behavior is to open the link in the app. However, if a user long presses on the link, they have the option to open the link in Safari.

[image]

This is the page in Safari. When the 'Open' button is clicked to open the link in the app, the website is opened instead of the app. This makes no sense considering the default behavior opens the link in the app. Any thoughts on what the problem could be?

[image]

Here is the dynamic link format (With the API key removed, so it does not work):
https://campuscosmo.page.link/?link=https://hippocampus-b50aa.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey%XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXcontinueUrl%3Dhttps://campuscosmo.com/openOnMobile.html%26lang%3Den&ibi=com.Stakeup.hippocampus.HippoCampus&ifl=https://hippocampus-b50aa.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey%XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26mode%3DsignIn%26oobCode%3DSS_k-J6W2i4OMXjcYqr-dyh7LEufGpFMTJejP9De9FIAAAF2lYCqkQ%26continueUrl%3Dhttps://campuscosmo.com/openOnMobile.html%26lang%3Den